# How to disable request validation in ASP.NET MVC running at IIS6?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have ASP.NET MVC application with action which should process posted XML data. At Cassini is working everything fine but when I deploy application to IIS6 I am getting following error.

```
A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the client (xml="<?xml version="1.0" ...").
```

I tried decorate controller with `ValidateInput(false)` attribute and I also add following method to controller.

```
protected override void Initialize(RequestContext requestContext)
{
  ValidateRequest = false;
  base.Initialize(requestContext);
}
```

Nothing help.

Do you have any other idea how can I get rid off this annoying request validation?

**Edit**: Sorry. I was totally my error as usual. After I setup wildcard mapping everything  is working fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is it (ValidateInput) on a POST method? It only works with POST.

Comment: Yes it is a post request that triggers this problem. I also tried to add AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post) and ValidateInput(false) to particular method but it seems it has now effect at IIS6.

Comment: Oddness- This should work. Are you definitely posting to that action, and not a different one?

Answer (score 2):

As Richard said, you should place it on the action method accepting the input:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateInput (false)]
public ActionResult DoTheThing (StuffBeingPostedBack stuff)
{
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Put [ValidateInput(false)] above your ActionResult in your controller's post methods....